# Next.js - route based modal

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When using Next.js, I want to show a modal based on a url, on top of another page.

If `gallery.js` is the page component, I want `/gallery/image/1232132` to display a modal with an image, on top of the gallery page.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

This question is a bit old, but since March 2020 there's a full example on the official Next.js repo (you should probably use this since it must be the "recommended way" by the maintainers):

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-route-as-modal

Here's the original issue:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8023

And the related PR:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/11473

Comment: Ok but this example give you either dynamic urls, or modals on top of the current page. It  does not show how to have a modal on top of the current page that persists on a refresh

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your question correctly you want to add deep links to the individual gallery items. This is possible, but you need a custom server to handle custom routes.

The first thing you need to do is setup the routes. I shared an example here: [using React router with Next JS route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116585/using-react-router-with-next-js-route/51451155#51451155).

```js
const nextRoutes = require('next-routes');
const routes = (module.exports = nextRoutes());

routes
    .add('gallery', '/gallery')
    .add('gallery-item', '/gallery/image/:image', 'gallery')
```

Then you can access this parameter in the `getInitialProps` method, and render the modal if the image parameter is set:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Gallery extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        image: PropTypes.string
    };
    
    static getInitialProps({query: {image}}) {
        return {image};
    }

    render() {
        const {image} = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
                {image &&
                    // render modal
                }
                // render gallery
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Nextjs 13.4 it is possible using [Intercepting Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/intercepting-routes)

> Intercepting routes allows you to load a route within the current layout while keeping the context for the current page. This routing paradigm can be useful when you want to "intercept" a certain route to show a different route.

For example, when clicking on a photo from within a feed, a modal overlaying the feed should show up with the photo. In this case, Next.js intercepts the `/feed` route and "masks" this URL to show `/photo/123` instead.

[image]

##### Convention to use

Intercepting routes can be defined with the (..) convention, which is similar to relative path convention ../ but for segments.

You can use:

- (.) to match segments on the same level
- (..) to match segments one level above
- (..)(..) to match segments two levels above
- (...) to match segments from the root app directory

[image]