# (Next.js) How do you handle internal links in text fetched from an API?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, next.js

Let's say I get content from a Wordpress post.

In several places, the article links to other internal articles.

These posts will link to `api.example.com/article` not `example.com/article.`

How does `Next.js` handle links that can't be hard-coded using `<Link />`?

Comment: Not sure about Next.js, but I ran into a [similar problem with React-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44549752/65387). You might want to dig into the source-code and see how they did it... you can probably pull something out if there's no public API.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with custom routing and JavaScript replace. First setup the custom routing as I described here: [Next.js - route based modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363962/next-js-route-based-modal/51488524#51488524)

Once this is setup create a route for the articles. Lets say for example you replace the link with `api.example.com/articles/:id`:

```js
const nextRoutes = require('next-routes');
const routes = (module.exports = nextRoutes());

routes
    .add('article', '/articles/:id', 'article')
```

Once these routes are setup your links should work. The one disadvantage of this approach is using standard links will force a reload on each page, since Next only supports browser rendering using its link module.

Comment: Yea, I figured it would involve replace. Really sucks that those links force a full reload. Kinda defeats the whole purpose of Next.js.

Comment: Yeah, I really like Next, but there is a lot of pretty standard web app functionality (parameterized routing for example) that requires custom configuration. On the other hand its a super active project and getting better every day. If you find a better solution please update this thread, I'm curious too.